# Firebase presence system: never stops writing

Tags: javascript, firebase

**Edit** To clarify: I have two issues.
1. Why is my node overwritten?
2. Why is the callback apparently being called recursivly?

I follow [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-sample) to implement a presence system to my webapp. I want all logged in users to always be able to know if all the other users are online or not.
Here is my code:

```
  currentGameRef = gamesInProgressRef.child(newState.currentTable);
  var myConnectionsRef = currentGameRef.child("player" + newState.myPlayerNumber).child("connections");
  var lastOnlineRef = currentGameRef.child("player" + newState.myPlayerNumber).child("lastOnline");

  var connectedRef = firebase.database().ref('.info/connected');
  connectedRef.on("value", function(snap) {
    if(snap.val() == true){
      var con = myConnectionsRef.push(true);
      con.onDisconnect().remove();

      lastOnlineRef.onDisconnect().set(firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
    }
  });
```

When I test the code, it writes thousands of `true` to each of the players "connections"-node. The wierd thing is that all the other children of each player is erased. Why is this happening?
A player node looks like this:

```
"player1" : {
  "name": "Vladimir Putin",
  "country": "Russia",
  ...,
  ...,
  "connections" : {
    ...
    ...
  }
}
```

I don't set the "player1"-node in my code, just a child of it. I know for a 100 % that it is the above code that causes this behaviour, but I cant figure out why. Can someone please tell me why the code above clears the player nodes?

Comment: what are the values of `snap.val()` ? is there a reason why you changed `===` to `==` ?

Comment: No, I just did that accidently. I changed it now. Same thing. The value of snap.val() has to be true since it enters the code snippet and pushes jet another true on the connections array.

Comment: What is this `newState` variable appearing in your code multiple times?

Comment: @vzsg It is a variable that contains the state of the React component

Comment: I have a guess as to why you have a lot of `true` entries. However, to better debug the bigger issue at hand... the deletion of other child nodes, could you please comment out `con.onDisconnect().remove();` once and check if the sibling cannibalism still occurs? Basically, I want to ensure if this line is causing it or now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that something went wrong with the variables that come with newState. I did this test here:

```
// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
  apiKey: '<your-api-key>',
  authDomain: '<your-auth-domain>',
  databaseURL: '<your-database-url>',
  storageBucket: '<your-storage-bucket>'
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

// fixed values just for test
var newState = {
  myPlayerNumber: 1,
  currentTable: 2
};

var gamesInProgressRef = firebase.database().ref('games');
currentGameRef = gamesInProgressRef.child(newState.currentTable);
var myConnectionsRef = currentGameRef.child("player" + newState.myPlayerNumber).child("connections");
var lastOnlineRef = currentGameRef.child("player" + newState.myPlayerNumber).child("lastOnline");

var connectedRef = firebase.database().ref('.info/connected');
connectedRef.on("value", function(snap) {
  if(snap.val() == true){
    var con = myConnectionsRef.push(true);
    con.onDisconnect().remove();
    lastOnlineRef.onDisconnect().set(firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
  }
});
```

And I have the following happening.

1) First client connected

[image: First client connected]

2) Second client connected

[image: Second client connected]

3) Both clients disconnected

[image: Both clients disconnected]

It seems to me that this is the desired result. So try to debug what is being used as newState, maybe your are getting 'undefined' or some other fixed value.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time. I will test this code in a while. I'll get back to you!